# while calling Axis2 web service from client it show following error it service works perfectly from browser

Tags: java, apache-axis

while calling Axis2 web service from client it show following error it service works perfectly from browser?

```
  [INFO] OMException in getSOAPBuilder
    org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '"' (code 34) in DOCTYPE declaration; expected a space between public and system identifiers
     at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,62]
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:204)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:154)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:140)
        at org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil.getSOAPBuilder(BuilderUtil.java:686)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:197)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:145)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:108)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:67)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:354)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
        at treasury.TreasuryStub.getdata(TreasuryStub.java:2044)
        at treasury.test.main(test.java:39)
    Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '"' (code 34) in DOCTYPE declaration; expected a space between public and system identifiers
     at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,62]`enter code here`
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:648)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.startDTD(BasicStreamReader.java:2482)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromPrologBang(BasicStreamReader.java:2398)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2058)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1069)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
```

how to solve this issue....?

Comment: Better if you can give more details, show your client code part

Comment: TreasuryStub ins_stub=new TreasuryStub();
     
  Getdata ins_get=new Getdata();
     
     ins_get.setUsername("parameter1");
     ins_get.setPassword("parameter3");
     ins_get.setUpday("parameter2");

     
     GetdataResponse response=ins_stub.getdata(ins_get);
     System.out.println("SOAP Response: "
                + response.getOMElement(null,
                        OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory())
                        .toStringWithConsume()); 
     
//     System.out.println("hello:::::::::"+response.get_return());
 }